# error: Invalid byte opcode: op=183, ptr=2

Tags: byte-compilation, cygwin, bytecode, wsl

I byte-compile my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. It was done by Emacs 26.1 from Cygwin and I got error when load `emacs-nox` 25.2 from Debian WSL:

```
error: Invalid byte opcode: op=183, ptr=2
```

Were new opcodes introduced into Emacs byte code starting from v26? For what purpose?

I have no issues to load byte compiled files between v22-v25...

Comment: Pretty much every major Emacs release breaks forward compatibility for .elc files, either by introducing new byte-codes (or macros whose expansion uses new functions).  If you were able to use Emacs-25-compiled files under Emacs-22 you were just lucky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [NEWS](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS?h=emacs-26.1#n1087):

```
* Incompatible Lisp Changes in Emacs 26.1
[...]
** Certain cond/pcase/cl-case forms are now compiled using a faster jump
table implementation.  This uses a new bytecode op 'switch', which
isn't compatible with previous Emacs versions.  This functionality can
be disabled by setting 'byte-compile-cond-use-jump-table' to nil.
```

Answer (score 6):

A *solution* to this is to delete all compiled EmacsLisp files in the user's Emacs directory

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/
find . -name "*.elc" -type f
```

Once you are satisfacted by what the find command returns (it should only return `.elc` files), delete them with the `-delete` option:

```
find . -name "*.elc" -type f -delete
```

Then restart Emacs and they will be regenerated when needed.

I added this as a function to my `.bashrc` because I honnestly use it all the time and I hate to have to search for the `find` syntax each time.

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is to have dedicated package directories for each Emacs version. You can do this by placing the following in your init file:

```
(setq package-user-dir (concat "~/.emacs.d/elpa/" emacs-version))
```